# How to remove unwanted space in wordpress OMG Blog theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[how to remove white space in the above picture? it is omg blog theme homepage. I already did padding:0 px , but still white space appears between header and media.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PCrz.png)

Comment: Can you post a link to that page?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `margin`
if you could post a link to your website, it would be easier to help you.